# How do you handle multiple Firebase collections within one Vue component?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I have one component called index.
This index has two sections: a banner section and news section.
Each these sections have their own Firebase collection, which include stuff like headlines and text that the user is able to enter, edit and delete. Each collection has their seperate create/edit pages.

My problem is that I only know how to get and delete data from ONE database table in a component, but here I have a component that hosts data from TWO database tables.
How do I get this to work?

Here is what I tried so far.

```
<script>
import db from '@/firebase/init'
export default {
  name: 'Index',
  data () {
    return {
      file: [],
      news_section: [],
      banner_section: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteText(id) {
      db.collection('news_section' + 'banner_section').doc(id).delete()
      .then(() => {

        this.news_section = this.news_section.filter(news => {
        return news.id != id
      }),
        this.banner_section = this.banner_section.filter(banner => {
        return banner.id != id
        })
      })
    }
  },
  created() {
    db.collection('news_section' + 'banner_section').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let news, banner = doc.data()
        news.id, banner.id = doc.id
        this.news_section.push(news)
        this.banner_section.push(banner)
      })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you explain with more detail what you want to achieve.  Are you willing to get the data as if a join was made?  or are you trying to get both collections by separate but either have both collections or have nothing?

Comment: Hello. I will try to explain. I have a banner on the page, which has some text inside it. That text is something that the page-admin can add or edit via an input field on a seperate page. That input field is linked to a database table called "banner_section". On the page I also have a textfield that belongs to a table called "news_section". I want to be able to GET and DELETE data from BOTH these tables on my index page.  I tried " db.collection('news_section' + 'banner_section').get()" in my Created method, but that does not work.